# How to forward the port of a remote executable via SSH without exposing the port on the remote system

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding

I have a program that I want to run on a remote system and allow access to the port only on the local system.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found that [ip2unix](https://github.com/nixcloud/ip2unix) works perfectly for most programs with ssh's unix-socket forwarding. However the program (rsession) does not seem to behave well and there seems a bug in ip2unix in this case.

Alternatively I can use [socket wrapper](https://cwrap.org/socket_wrapper.html), which works, but sucks because I seem to have to use socat to open another socket, that I may actually forward via ssh and even worse, the process is totally isolated outbound.

So I still am wondering if there is other ways to achieve this more elegantly. (without having root access on either system)